# Is it possible to notify DTrace on Mac OS X of dynamically generated code?

Tags: macos, mono, jit, dtrace

We would like to extend Mono's VM to generate information that can be consumed by [DTrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace) and instruments.

I am looking at making changes to the Mono runtime to have it register or notify the code that it has dynamically generated so DTrace can produce useful information for those blocks of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What kind of information do you want to include?

The main example of doing this is ustack helpers, which convey from a VM to DTrace how to translate stack frames into human-readable frames. These have existed for Python, Java, and Node.js.

Here's a "hello world" ustack helper:
https://github.com/davepacheco/ustack

and here's the one for Node.js:
https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/v8ustack.d

Comment: I've seen various posts that say this isn't possible on Mac OS X.  Are those out of date?

Comment: This is still true.  Here's a post from last March: 
http://www.mail-archive.com/dtrace-discuss@opensolaris.org/msg04668.html

but it's still true on OSX SL and Lion.  If you want this, please file a bug report at bugreport.apple.com, as that's the best way for the community to escalate this with Apple.